Invariant bilinear form of irreducible representation of Hopf algebra
Given a Hopf algebra $H$ and an irreducible representation $\pi$ on a vector space $\mathcal V$, which is possibly infinite-dimensional, suppose I am able to find an invariant bilinear form $\Psi(\cdot\otimes\cdot)$ on $\mathcal V\otimes\mathcal{V}$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
\Psi\left((\pi\otimes\pi)(\Delta\xi)(f_1\otimes f_2)\right)=\epsilon(\xi)\Psi\left(f_1\otimes f_2\right),\qquad \forall \xi\in H,\quad f_1,f_2\in\mathcal{V}\ ,
\end{equation}
where $\Delta$ is the co-multiplication and $\epsilon$ is the co-unit of $H$. Is the invariant bilinear form on $\mathcal V\otimes\mathcal{V}$ unique up to multiplying a scalar?
Thanks in advance for your answers!
